# Is initChain method useless in the file peer.go hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When we invoke command `peer node start` to start peer node, or 
command `peer join channel -c xxx.block` , it will invoke `peer.InitChain(chainID)` method in the peer.go file,
but I think the code is useless . I annotation it，and peer node doesn't have any problem. As the system code such lscc、cscc、qscc and so on have been started  using peer.go file following code:

```
//initialize system chaincodes
    initSysCCs()
```

so I think the file peer.go has the useless method InitChain(cid string) ?

the method will use the system chaincode in exectransaction.go with method

```
//Execute - execute proposal, return original response of chaincode
func Execute(ctxt context.Context, cccid *ccprovider.CCContext, spec interface{}) (*pb.Response, *pb.ChaincodeEvent, error) {
```

and finnally reaches to chaincode_support.go,

```
if notfy, err = chrte.handler.sendExecuteMessage(ctxt, cccid.ChainID, msg, cccid.SignedProposal, cccid.Proposal); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error sending %s: %s", msg.Type.String(), err)
}
```

chainID doesn't affect handler to deal with,and the invoke following:

```
func (handler *Handler) sendExecuteMessage(ctxt context.Context, chainID string, msg *pb.ChaincodeMessage, signedProp *pb.SignedProposal, prop *pb.Proposal) (chan *pb.ChaincodeMessage, error) {
    txctx, err := handler.createTxContext(ctxt, chainID, msg.Txid, signedProp, prop)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if chaincodeLogger.IsEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG) {
        chaincodeLogger.Debugf("[%s]Inside sendExecuteMessage. Message %s", shorttxid(msg.Txid), msg.Type.String())
    }

    //if security is disabled the context elements will just be nil
    if err = handler.setChaincodeProposal(signedProp, prop, msg); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    chaincodeLogger.Debugf("[%s]sendExecuteMsg trigger event %s", shorttxid(msg.Txid), msg.Type)
    handler.triggerNextState(msg, true)     //**when triggerNextState, chainId field is useless.** 

    return txctx.responseNotifier, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to the the [peer.InitChain(cid string)](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/peer/peer.go#L126) method, so I do not think it's useless. Honestly I'm not completely sure about your explanation as it's a bit hard to follow, but this function being used upon peer initialization. E.g. the function being called from [peer.Initialize(init func(string))](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/peer/peer.go#L92) method to be precise [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/peer/peer.go#L121) is the line:

```
        // Skipped rest of the code

        // Create a chain if we get a valid ledger with config block
        if err = createChain(cid, ledger, cb); err != nil {
            peerLogger.Warningf("Failed to load chain %s(%s)", cid, err)
            peerLogger.Debugf("Error reloading chain %s with message %s. We continue to the next chain rather than abort.", cid, err)
            continue
        }

        InitChain(cid)
}
```

The role of this method is to call for initializer which being passed in [start.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/peer/node/start.go#L191):

```
//this brings up all the chains (including testchainid)
peer.Initialize(func(cid string) {
    logger.Debugf("Deploying system CC, for chain <%s>", cid)
    scc.DeploySysCCs(cid)
})
```

basically deploying system chaincodes. Please note that in `peer.Initialize` method assigns [chainInializer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/peer/peer.go#L81), which is called via `peer.InitChain`.

```
func Initialize(init func(string)) {
    chainInitializer = init

    var cb *common.Block
    var ledger ledger.PeerLedger
    ledgermgmt.Initialize()
    ledgerIds, err := ledgermgmt.GetLedgerIDs()
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Error in initializing ledgermgmt: %s", err))
}
```

So to your question, no this is not useless code. Also note to the difference:

```
//initialize system chaincodes
initSysCCs()
```

implemented as following:

```
func initSysCCs() {
    //deploy system chaincodes
    scc.DeploySysCCs("")
    logger.Infof("Deployed system chaincodes")
}
```

note the fact that `chainID==""`, while following code:

```
//this brings up all the chains (including testchainid)
peer.Initialize(func(cid string) {
    logger.Debugf("Deploying system CC, for chain <%s>", cid)
    scc.DeploySysCCs(cid)
})
```

deploys chaincode for specific channel id, e.g. `scc.DeploySysCCs(cid)`.

Going down the path you can spot the difference at [sysccapi.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/sysccapi.go#L92), where `deploySysCC` implemented as:

```
// deploySysCC deploys the given system chaincode on a chain
func deploySysCC(chainID string, syscc *SystemChaincode) error {
    if !syscc.Enabled || !isWhitelisted(syscc) {
        sysccLogger.Info(fmt.Sprintf("system chaincode (%s,%s) disabled", syscc.Name, syscc.Path))
        return nil
    }

    var err error

    ccprov := ccprovider.GetChaincodeProvider()

    txid := util.GenerateUUID()

    ctxt := context.Background()
    if chainID != "" {
        lgr := peer.GetLedger(chainID)
        if lgr == nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("syschain %s start up failure - unexpected nil ledger for channel %s", syscc.Name, chainID))
        }

        //init can do GetState (and other Get's) even if Puts cannot be
        //be handled. Need ledger for this
        ctxt2, txsim, err := ccprov.GetContext(lgr, txid)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        ctxt = ctxt2

        defer txsim.Done()
    }

    chaincodeID := &pb.ChaincodeID{Path: syscc.Path, Name: syscc.Name}
    spec := &pb.ChaincodeSpec{Type: pb.ChaincodeSpec_Type(pb.ChaincodeSpec_Type_value["GOLANG"]), ChaincodeId: chaincodeID, Input: &pb.ChaincodeInput{Args: syscc.InitArgs}}

    // First build and get the deployment spec
    chaincodeDeploymentSpec, err := buildSysCC(ctxt, spec)

    if err != nil {
        sysccLogger.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Error deploying chaincode spec: %v\n\n error: %s", spec, err))
        return err
    }

    version := util.GetSysCCVersion()

    cccid := ccprov.GetCCContext(chainID, chaincodeDeploymentSpec.ChaincodeSpec.ChaincodeId.Name, version, txid, true, nil, nil)

    _, _, err = ccprov.ExecuteWithErrorFilter(ctxt, cccid, chaincodeDeploymentSpec)

    sysccLogger.Infof("system chaincode %s/%s(%s) deployed", syscc.Name, chainID, syscc.Path)

    return err
}
```

Note the following peace of code inside:

```
    ctxt := context.Background()
    if chainID != "" {
        lgr := peer.GetLedger(chainID)
        if lgr == nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("syschain %s start up failure - unexpected nil ledger for channel %s", syscc.Name, chainID))
        }

        //init can do GetState (and other Get's) even if Puts cannot be
        //be handled. Need ledger for this
        ctxt2, txsim, err := ccprov.GetContext(lgr, txid)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        ctxt = ctxt2

        defer txsim.Done()
    }
```

Comment: May the biggest difference is following:  sysccapi.go file

 `ccprov := ccprovider.GetChaincodeProvider()

 ctxt := context.Background()
 if chainID != "" {
  lgr := peer.GetLedger(chainID)
  if lgr == nil {
   panic(fmt.Sprintf("syschain %s start up failure - unexpected nil ledger for channel %s", syscc.Name, chainID))
  }

  _, err := ccprov.GetContext(lgr)
  if err != nil {
   return err
  }

  defer ccprov.ReleaseContext()
 }` 
 when trace ` ccprov.GetContext(lgr)` ,it creates  txsimulator with ccprov member variant.